# Compute expected standard deviation from proportion data

Tags: standard-deviation

This example is from the first chapter of Gelman & Hill 2007:

> > The following are the proportions of girl births in Vienna for each month in     1908 and 1909 (out of an average of 3900 births per month):
> >
> > .4777 .4875 .4859 .4754 .4874 .4864 .4813 .4787 .4895 .4797 .4876 .4859 .4857 .4907 .5010 .4903 .4860 .4911 .4871 .4725 .4822 .4870 .4823 .4973
> >
> > The data are in the folder girls. von Mises (1957) used these proportions to claim that the sex ratios were less variable than would be expected by chance.
> >
> > Compute the standard deviation of these proportions and compare to the standard deviation that would be expected if the sexes of babies were inde- pendently decided with a constant probability over the 24-month period.

---

The standard deviation is: 0.064

I'm wondering how to calculate the expected standard deviation? Should I use a binomial model? but where do the probabilities come from then?

EDIT:

The next step would be to assess whether the observed (0.0064) and chance (0.0080) deviations significantly differ.

The exercise gives a hint: "under the randomness model, the actual variance should have a distribution with expected value equal to the theoretical variance, and proportional to a chi^2 with 23 degrees of freedom"

I'm wondering how I could assess whether the two deviations are significantly different. The only solution I can come up with is

(observed-expected^2)/expected = (0.0064-0.0080)^2/0.0080 = 0.00032 and then compare this to a chi^2 distribution with 23 degrees of freedom. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: In general, the variance of the sample variance can be quite complicated (and involves higher moments). It seems unlikely you are expected to use it here.

Answer (score 3):

I think your calculated standard deviation for the proportions is $0.0064$ (note extra 0).

Yes,  to calculate the expected standard deviation, you are probably expected to use a binomial model and the formula $\sqrt{\dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}}.$ You can take the mean of your sample data to give you an estimate of $p$, though taking $0.5$ will give much the same result in practice. $n$ comes from "out of an average of 3900 births per month".

Comment: thanks! so the expected would be 0.0080 and the observed is 0.0064. Now to check whether this difference is significant I could run a X^2 test. Can I do it the following way: (observed - expected)ˆ2/expected and compare it to the Xˆ2 distribution?

Comment: I suppose you could, but for a $\chi^2$ test you want frequencies rather than proportions.  You would not be using the standard deviations in the test.

Comment: That chi-squared test would have zero degrees of freedom :-).

Answer (score 1):

To assess whether difference between the observed (0.0064) and chance (0.0080) deviations is statistically significant, you can also compute the 95% confidence interval of the chance standard deviation. This is where the chi^2 distribution with 23 degrees of freedom comes to the picture; you need the quantiles of this distribution, among others, to form this confidence interval. Once you have the confidence interval, check if the observed deviation is inside the interval; if it is, then the difference between the observed and chance deviations is not statistically significant.

Answer (score 0):

Very late response, but regarding the goodness-of-fit test to the binomial distribution, it turns out that this
$$
s^2(n-1)/\sigma^2
$$
has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, where $s$ is the sample standard deviation and $\sigma$ is the expected standard deviation.

The formula above will produce a test statistic whose p-value you can compute against that distribution. Because the observed variance is “too small”, you want the left-tailed probability (ie, the probability of getting a statistic smaller than the calculated value).